# npm-auth0 error Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, axios, next.js

I'm trying to use [npm-auth0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth0).

I keep getting this error.

```
./node_modules/auth0/src/management/JobsManager.js:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
null
```

I have tried to resolve by uninstalling and reinstalling
also I have tried a module.export alteration which I seen on another stack question with no success.

```
import { AuthenticationClient, ManagementClient } from "auth0";


const Profile = () => {


  const auth0 = new ManagementClient({
    domain: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL,
    clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
    scope: "read:users update:users",
  });
```

Comment: `node-auth0` is a Node.js library, it can't be used in the browser. Try moving the `auth0` code to the server-side (`getServerSideProps` or API routes).

Comment: thanks I will give it a go